# What results did set theory approach yielded

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is a zfc set theoretical approach to numbers and counting.
While this is interesting, was there an impactful theorem that relies on set theory in counting. Or is it more like "it helps us to lay the foundations to counting"?

Comment: It's merely one system to formalize mathematics. Certain results are true or false or unprovable in it, and the status of those results might differ in a different formalization system. In this sense, there are indeed theorems "specific to ZF(C)", but whether you accept ZF(C) or not is more a philosophical matter. In practice, careful usage of naive set theory is what almost every mathematician uses to actually do maths, with some moral idea that the meaning should be independent of the formalization

Comment: Do you consider Goodstein's theorem (it says that some way of constructing sequence of numbers always give finite sequences, it can be proved in ZF, but not in PA) to rely on set theory?

Comment: For the concept of counting , we only need PA , not ZF , but ZF is much more powerful and can prove statements that PA cannot prove.